# PHP timezone offset in hrs

Tags: php, date, timezone

I want to be able to set `Timezone` offset in hours like in select' options: `-1, 0,+1,+2..`  then apply it's value to php `date`. But it's a 1st time i work with date fn.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date("l");
echo'</br>';
echo date("g").':';
echo date("i");
?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at strtotime() function of php. It may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

echo date("l");
echo'</br>';

//+1,-1,0....any value
echo date("g", strtotime("+1 hour")).':';
echo date("i");
```